# restriction about default capture mode and 'this' in C++ lambda-expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I'm wondering why `=` *capture-default* mode prohibits `this` in *capture-list* of C++ *lambda expression*.

That is,

```
[=, this]{ };  // error
[&, this]{ };  // OK
```

This is specified by C++11 5.1.2/8.

> - If a lambda-capture includes a capture-default that is &, the
>     identifiers in the lambda-capture shall not be preceded by &.
> - If a lambda-capture includes a capture-default that is =, the
>     lambda-capture shall not contain this and each identifier it contains
>     shall be preceded by &.

Q: Is there any reason or background story for this rule?

Comment: Isn't `this` implicitly captured anyway when the capture-default is `=`?

Comment: @Benj Yes, `this` is implicitly captured under both `=` and `&` capture-default.

Comment: It makes me wonder if `this` is actually always captured by reference irrespective of the default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this` can only be captured by copy and *never* by reference. Even if you specify only `[&]`, `this` can be implicitly captured by copy if odr-used. Therefore, `[=, this]` is an error because `=` would already implicitly capture `this` by copy while the `&` in `[&, this]` signifies capture by reference and does not implicitly capture `this` (unless it is odr-used)

Comment: I'm a little confused. Doesn't `[&]` (not `[&,this]`) implicitly capture `this`?

Comment: No, `[&]` doesn't implicitly capture `this` by default. **However**, if you odr-use `this` inside the curly braces `{}` such as when accessing a member variable, etc., **then** it is implicitly captured by `[&]` (but it *still* is captured by copy and not reference).

Comment: What does odr-used mean?

Comment: @TimMB: Have you heard of the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)? It is an important concept and related to the term odr-used. 3.2p3 in the C++ standard defines the meaning of odr-used. Basically, when a name is odr-used, it requires a definition and is subject to the one definition rule.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks, I had not read the definition of the rule although I was familiar with it through experience. However, I still don't understand how it applies in this case.

Comment: @TimMB: A pointer to an object of class type does not require a definition as it does not require the object to be complete. However, any type of member access via the this pointer would require a definition of the class of the member you are accessing. In relation to lambdas, the `this` pointer is implicitly captured only if you perform some type of member access or evaluation of the this pointer from within the lambda body, which makes the this pointer odr-used.