# C++11 variable capture with lambda inside another lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

In node.js I can write lambda inside lambda and capture whichever variable I want. But in C++11, as lambda functions are actually functor object, variable capturing is not so easy with nested lambdas.

I'm using `[this]` to capture this pointer so I can use class members. But inside a lambda, `this` pointer points to the lambda instead of the outter class.

```
void MyClass::myFunction() {
    // call the lambda1
    connect(action, trigger, [this]() {
        // in the lambda1, call lambda2
        sendCommand([this]() {      // <-- I want `this` point to the outter class
            this->myMember.log("something");  // myMember is the member of class MyClass
        });
    });
}
```

I know it can be done by rename this to another pointer variable and capture that variable instead of `this`, but I think that way is ugly.

Is there any better way to capture outter `this`?

Comment: @BЈовић Why would capturing `this` implicitly by copy be in any way "better" than capturing it explicitly by copy?

Comment: @Casey My mistake. I really meant `[&]`

Comment: @BЈовић It doesn't make sense to capture `this` by reference since it is a prvalue. Indeed, the standard does not allow explicitly capturing `this` by reference: both `[&this]` and `[=,this]` are explicitly forbidden. Allowing implicit capture of `this` by reference is probably an error in the standard. Compilers treat implicit reference capture as capture by copy. (See [restriction about default capture mode and 'this' in C++ lambda-expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989774/restriction-about-default-capture-mode-and-this-in-c-lambda-expression) for more discussion.)

Answer (score 3):

You simply capture outer lambda's context:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Omg
{
  int lol= 42;

  Omg()
  {
    [this]{ [&]{ std::cout<< this-> lol; }(); }();
  }
};

int main(){ Omg(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

> But inside a lambda, `this` pointer points to the lambda instead of the outter class.

No, inside the lambda `this` has the same value as outside. The only problem in your code is accessing `this` with `.` instead of `->`. This program:

```
void MyClass::myFunction() {
    std::cout << this << std::endl;
    // call the lambda1
    connect(action, trigger, [this]() {
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
        // in the lambda1, call lambda2
        sendCommand([this]() {      // <-- I want `this` point to the outter class
            std::cout << this << std::endl;
            this->myMember.log("something");  // myMember is the member of class MyClass
        });
    });
}
```

[Prints the same value for this in all three places](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8675eeb13b245db0):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
0x7fff4286c80f
0x7fff4286c80f
0x7fff4286c80f
```

N3936 (C++14 Working Draft) [expr.prim.lambda]/18 states:

> Every *id-expression* within the *compound-statement* of a *lambda-expression* that is an odr-use (3.2) of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type. [ *Note:* An *id-expression* that is not an odr-use refers to the original entity, never to a member of the closure type. Furthermore, such an *id-expression* does not cause the implicit capture of the entity. —*end note* ] If `this` is captured, each odr-use of `this` is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type, cast (5.4) to the type of `this`. [ *Note:* The cast ensures that the transformed expression is a prvalue. —*end note* ]

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the code above (I've fixed it, now `this->` instead of `this.`).

Comment: I tried your method but failed. I printed out two different value of `this`: ffffe190 and ffffba53. I'm doing this in Qt and use std::function<> as the type of callback.

Comment: @songziming Sounds like a compiler bug. [Are you by any chance using VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020337/nested-lambda-capture-in-c)?